# Responsive nav order reversed when it goes into mobile media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav

I'm trying to create a responsive nav with a logo from the w3c example. However, I have run into an issue with the nav. When I float the element to the right of the page the order of the nav items is messed up. I have reordered them on the desktop version but I can't seem to order them correctly in the mobile nav. I have tried using floats but that just messes up the styling of the dropdown.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxKpxj)

```
    </head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
         <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
  html{
    min-height:100%;
}

body{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
/* min-height:100%;*/
/*   position:relative;*/
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
    margin:0 auto;
}


.topnav img{
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right:40px;


}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: right;
/*    position: relative;*/
    display: inline;
/*    display: inline-block;*/
    color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}



/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
/*      clear: both;*/
}


  .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
        height:210px; 

    }

  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
        clear: both;
/*      position: relative;*/
        top:0px;
/*      height:100%;*/
    float: none;
    display: block;
/*    text-align: center;*/
  }

  .topnav a {
        display: none;
    }

  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  } 


}
```

JS

```
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add extra markup and change order in html and then add to css two selectors *.container-nav*

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
/*   margin: 0 auto; */
/*   padding: 0; */
/*   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; */
/*   height: 100%; */
/*   width: 100%; */
}

#container {
/*   margin: 0 auto; */
/*   height: 100%; */
/*   width: 100%; */
  /* min-height:100%;*/
  /*   position:relative;*/
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
/*   margin: 0 auto; */
}

.topnav img {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav .container-nav{
  float:right;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  /*   position: relative;*/
/*   display: inline-block; */
/*      display: inline-block; */
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #4caf00;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 52px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*  clear: both;*/
  }

  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    height: 210px;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav .container-nav{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    clear: both;
    /*  position: relative;*/
    top: 0px;
    /*  height:100%;*/
    float: none;
    display: block;
/*        text-align: center; */
  }

  .topnav a {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav .icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: -31.6px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
      
      <div class="container-nav">
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      </div>

      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

I can also suggest to read a little about specificity :)

Comment: Thank you, that has worked, however now the hamburger menu is below the logo creating a bigger nav bar. it goes to the correct position when it is clicked however.

Comment: I changed CSS. Try it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit, mainly added a container for the clickable links, moved the icon at the top and order can be same.

CSS:

```
html{
    min-height:100%;
}

body{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
/* min-height:100%;*/
/*   position:relative;*/
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.topnav .nav-item-container {
  float:right;
}
.topnav img{
    float:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right:40px;


}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
/*    position: relative;*/
    display: inline;
/*    display: inline-block;*/
    color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}



/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .topnav {
        background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
/*      clear: both;*/
}


  .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
        height:210px; 

    }

  .topnav .nav-item-container{
    padding-top:    0px; 
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
        clear: both;
/*      position: relative;*/
        top:0px;
/*      height:100%;*/
    float: none;
    display: block;
/*    text-align: center;*/
  }

  .topnav a {
        display: none;
    }

  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  } 


}
```

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
<div class="nav-item-container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>


</div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

The above should be able to display in the same order which you want. Hope this helps!